# Do Peano curves provide a counterargument to Grothendieck's critique?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, soft-question, space-filling-curves

This question arose in the context of [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236060) on Grothendieck's critique of the traditional foundations of topology. Can the paper *Group Invariant Peano Curves* by Cannon and Thurston be regarded as exhibiting the naturality of phenomena like space-filling curves previously regarded as odd?

To clarify, the notion of *naturality* is not mine but rather is implied by Grothendieck's critique of the foundations of topology; see the earlier question linked above (perhaps he even uses the term *natural*, I would have to double-check). According to that view, odd phenomena like space-fillling curves are an artifice of the foundations. The question is whether the Cannon-Thurston paper finds them to be actually useful for something, which may be an argument against Grotendieck's criticism.

Comment: Did you have a mathematically precise concept of "natural" in mind? I think there is no universally agreed-upon concept of what counts as natural.

Comment: "...regarded as exhibiting the naturality of phenomena..." ?

Comment: See my clarification in the question.

Comment: Yes, space-filling curves appear in the wild, even though they may seem to be contrived at first. There is a natural $S^1$ at infinity for a hyperbolic surface, and a natural $S^2$ at infinity for a hyperbolic $3$-manifold, and it might be that when you have a surface in a $3$-manifold that there is a well-defined map from the $S^1$ at infinity to the $S^2$ at infinity that is continuous and onto. The Hopf fibration is also natural even if it seems strange at first.

Comment: @Douglas, note that for Fuchsian groups (a.k.a. surfaces) the circle at infinity is pretty tame and it is only when you start looking at subgroups of Kleinian groups that you get wilder behavior for the limit set. Also notice that these are not space-filling curves since they are still homeomorphic to a circle. I personally have nothing against space-filling curves but I am just wondering if this is because of their intrinsic merit or because of what Grothendieck describes as...

Comment: ..."the almost insurmountable inertia of the mind, burdened by a heavy weight of conditioning, which makes it difficult to take a real look at a foundational question, thus at the context in which we live, breathe, work – accepting it, rather, as immutable data."

Comment: In my understanding, Grothendieck does not say that wild phenomena do not exist, but that an inadequate formalism diverts our attention from our initial problems to problems which are irrelevant to the given situation (he mentions Brouwer's invariance of the domain as an example). Also, Grothendieck insists that the category of good spaces should allow for reasonable constructions. He also mentions that these good spaces should have triangulation. (All of this is realized by o-minimal geometries.) ...

Comment: @ACL, I agree.  My understanding is that he is saying that things like invariance of domain should be easy consequences once the "right" definitions are in place.

Comment: ... so my interpretation of the Cannon/Thurston paper you mention is that such objects are not tame in Grothendieck's sense.  However, I do not know whether the problem lies in the specific hyperbolic 3-manifold fibered over the circle or in its universal covering...

Comment: I can't really comment intelligently on Cannon-Thurston since I haven't read it and nobody bothered to summarize it yet.

Comment: NB. O-minimal geometries have cellular decompositions and a good theory  of dimension, so that invariance of domain is obvious (once the machinery is set up). A natural theory of dimension is of course prevented by the existence of space-filling curves.

Comment: @ACL, I think you have a fine answer to my question posted [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225646). Could you contribute something there?

Comment: @Mikhail Katz, I don't understand why you were so dismissive of my comment. I tried to explain how space filling curves arise naturally in the Cannon and Thurston paper for non-topologists, and you say "no one has bothered to summarize it..." If you want to throw out these space-filling curves that arise from important structures (surface bundles over circles) that were defined earlier, what part of mathematics do you need to destroy? Can we not look at hyperbolic structures any more, since they might produce space filling curves?

Comment: @DouglasZare, I appreciated your comment. I was merely pointing out that I was not familiar with the Cannon-Thurston paper. In fact I am still not familiar with it, so it is hard to comment meaningfully on it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Have you read the abstract?

Answer (score 1):

Here I am expanding Doug Zare's comment into an answer.

---

The original poster asks:

> Can the paper Group Invariant Peano Curves by Cannon and Thurston be regarded as exhibiting the naturality of phenomena like space-filling curves previously regarded as odd?

and

> The question is whether the Cannon-Thurston paper finds them to be actually useful for something, which may be an argument against Grothendieck's criticism.

I do not have to hand Grothendieck's definition of "natural" nor the poster's definition of "useful for something", so I will substitute my own.

---

I take "naturality" to mean "without making many choices" and thus "having unexpectedly good properties".  For the various Peano curves, many choices are needed.  There are more-or-less simple recursive constructions, but this only underlines the fact that you could bolt these together in various ways to get uncountably many examples.

On the other hand, to obtain a Cannon-Thurston map, only two choices are required: first a fibered hyperbolic three-manifold $M$ and second a fibering of $M$.

With the real choices out of the way, the construction of the CT map is as follows.  We choose (but this does effect the eventual answer) an elevation of $F$ - that is, an embedding of the universal cover of $F$ into the universal cover of $M$.  The former is a copy of $\mathbb{H}^2$ while the latter is a copy of $\mathbb{H}^3$.  Any hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ has a boundary at infinity - this is a copy of the sphere $S^{n-1}$.  Thus we obtain a map $\phi \colon S^1 \to S^2$. That this map is continuous requires work.  That it is sphere-filling (and finite-to-one, and has certain invariance properties) is easier.

Note that if $N \to M$ is a finite cover, then the fibering of $M$ induces one of $N$.  Let $G$ be the fiber in $N$. Thus there is a covering map $G \to F$.  The CT maps associated to $(M, F)$ and $(N, G)$ are then isomorphic, and there is a diagram expressing the commutivity.

---

This is also useful for various things.  For example, Mahan Mj has used the existence of (more general) CT maps to prove that the limit set of a (finitely generated) Kleinian group is locally connected; see his [talk](https://youtu.be/BGk2FYiHEhk?t=1999) at the 2018 ICM.

Comment: I found Mj only as a moderator, not a speaker, at the 2022 ICM.  Do you have a link?

Comment: Perhaps this is the intended talk (at ICM 2018)?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGk2FYiHEhk

Comment: My mistake - I will fix the reference to Mahan Mj and will add the link.

Comment: I’m curious. How does one pronounce Mj? Is it an abbreviation or an actual name?

Comment: It is an abbreviation - sort of like how "Dr" stands for "Doctor".  His "actual" name is Mahan Mitra, but he no longer uses it, I think.  Ah, he has a wikipedia page -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahan_Mj -- so you can find references there.  (Oh, and I would just say "mij".  Or just "Hey, Mahan, good to see you again!")

Comment: The wikipedia page was the first place I looked at, and found no explanation there. So what does Mj stand for?

Comment: The second line of the wikipedia page says that his name is also "Mahan Maharaj".  So perhaps Mj is a shortening of "Maharaj".  However, I vaguely remember that him mentioning a much longer title?  I am afraid that if you want a definitive answer you'll have to ask Mahan.

Comment: All right, thank you. Yes, it did occur to me that it might stand for Maharaj, but then trying to confirm it with another search, I came out empty-handed. That's why I decided to ask here, thinking that someone may know it first-hand.